# Can't execute debug task in NetBeans after switching to Gradle

Tags: java, netbeans, gradle, netbeans-plugins

I've installed the Gradle-support plugin in Netbeans and I can build and run the project just fine. When I try to run in debug mode, I get the following output:

```
Executing: gradle debug

:debug
Cannot execute debug because the property "mainClass" is not defined or empty.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.222 secs
```

I'm using:

```
 Oracle Java 1.8
 Gradle 1.12
 Netbeans 8.0
 Gradle-Support 1.3.0
 LinuxMint 16
```

Why can't I run my debugger?

Comment: Shouldn't the missing defined mainClass also inhibit the running of the project?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add something like

```
if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = 'com.foo.acme.Main'
}
```

to your `build.gradle`. It will tell Gradle plugin what class to use when starting your application. Perhaps that should be customizable in the UI but I cannot see it now.

Comment: This seems to have launched the application but its not linking to native libraries, which causes an exception. Do I need to explicitly set the java.library.path again?

Comment: I suppose. Either make sure the working directory is what you expect it to be or set `java.library.path` or possibly `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env var. I haven't tried it native libraries.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer, I don't have a chance to check the lib path stuff right now but this fixed the original issue.

Comment: The runtime arguments are not in the UI as far as I know; this is an open issue on the Netbeans-Gradle plugin.  See: [Cannot pass arguments to main method](https://github.com/kelemen/netbeans-gradle-project/issues/194)  also there may be other not-yet-IDE type issues, e.g: [Gradle tasks should be started in own process - current directory should be netbeans project dir](https://github.com/kelemen/netbeans-gradle-project/issues/192).

Comment: A generic issue with Java applications programming (including the server-side) is that as a developer your Build/Compile environment may require a different Run-time context.  So it is not just arguments and working folder; there are libary and ClassPath issues; JNI context, AppServer version and context, etc.  It is here I take my hat off to JetBrains they usually seem to get to cover all options.

Answer (score 11):

Another solution to this problem is to create a new debug task. Similar to the gradle `run` task you can just add the following task to your `build.gradle` file:

```
task debug(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
    debug = true
}
```

Comment: This fixed the problem for me.  It is a strange thing.  I moved the main() Class  sub-project to a different root-project.  The `run` command still works.  And `debug` _stopped_ working.  After defining this `task debug()...` it is clear the problem was the `workingDir` was not being set to the right path.  Whereas the `run{ }` task sets the correct `workingDir`.  Until now, I thought the debug was a run with a `debug` flag set to `true`.  No so apparently.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [Radim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23422735/1536976) the way to customize the `mainClass` parameter in the Netbeans UI.

[image]

In the properties of a Netbeans gradle project go to "Built-In Tasks/Debug", unclick the "Inherit" and add "-PmainClass=aaa.bbb.ccc" to the arguments.

I guess this should also be done for the run task.

It's the same idea like run/debug single file which already take the selected file as parameter mainClass.

Answer (score 1):

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578918/cannot-build-gradle-project-with-gradle-support-plugin-for-netbeans-8-1) and was able to fix it setting *Options / Miscellaneous / Gradle / Task Execution / Automatic tasks* to "NetBeans should not add tasks automatically".