# Cannot build Gradle project with Gradle Support plugin for NetBeans 8.1

Tags: java, netbeans, gradle

I started a learning project to get familiar with Gradle, Spring and Vaadin. So far, I successfully created basic CRUD functionality with the help of some Spring guides.

Now I want to import the project into NetBeans. I installed the [Gradle Support plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/44510/gradle-support) for NetBeans and cloned my repository into a new NetBeans project.

When I try to `build` or `bootRun` the project within NetBeans, it fails, telling me that the main class cannot be found. But when I `build` or `bootRun` directly from the command line using the gradle wrapper I loaded into the repository, it works fine.

I studied every single page of the [Gradle Support plugin's wiki on GitHub](https://github.com/kelemen/netbeans-gradle-project/wiki) but couldn't find any information relevant to my problem.

Here's the output I get when trying to run the project in NetBeans via the project's context menu action *Tasks/build/build*:

```
Executing: gradle :build

:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:findMainClass FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':findMainClass'.
> Could not find property 'main' on task ':run'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.957 secs



Build failure (see the Notifications window for stacktrace): gradle :build
```

I pasted the mentioned [stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/anothernode/9702b280bf5751fd50ca#file-gistfile1-txt) to Gist.

And here's the output I get for the successful build executed from the command line on the very same project:

```
$ ./gradlew build
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:findMainClass
:jar
:bootRepackage
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 11.673 secs
```

I have really no idea how to go on with this and would greatly appreciate any hints and I find it very odd that I get different results when running from command line and when running from within NetBeans. Shouldn't the NetBeans plugin just be calling the same commands that I use directly on the command line and that work fine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found two ways to fix this since.

a) Adding

```
if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = 'org.foo.Bar'
}
```

to `build.gradle`.

b) Setting *Options / Miscellaneous / Gradle / Task Execution / Automatic tasks* to "NetBeans should not add tasks automatically".

This comment I found in a `build.gradle` file generated by NetBeans gave me the crucial hint:

```
// NetBeans will automatically add "run" and "debug" tasks relying on the
// "mainClass" property. You may however define the property prior executing
// tasks by passing a "-PmainClass=<QUALIFIED_CLASS_NAME>" argument.
//
// Note however, that you may define your own "run" and "debug" task if you
// prefer. In this case NetBeans will not add these tasks but you may rely on
// your own implementation.
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error when using the latest version of spring-boot-gradle-plugin (1.3.1.RELEASE). After downgrading to 1.2.8.RELEASE the error disappeared.

There has been some configuration changes in 1.3.x, see under Gradle plugin here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.3-Release-Notes

Maybe version resolution is different in NetBeans Gradle vs. command line. So you could try specify version 1.2.8, or update the config according to the 1.3 changes.

Comment: When I specify version 1.2.8 for the Spring Boot Gradle  plugin, I get a `ModelBuildingException` when running `gradle`.

I also tried to adjust `build.gradle` according to what I red in the release notes for version 1.3 you provided a link for, but same result as described in original post.