# gradle: Cannot execute run because the property "mainClass" is not defined or empty

Tags: java, netbeans, gradle, jar, manifest

The [project](https://github.com/THUFIR/hello_client) builds, and runs, from the CLI fine:

```
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/hello_client$ 
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/hello_client$ gradle clean build;java -jar build/libs/hello_client.jar 
:clean
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.032 secs
hello world
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/hello_client$
```

but Netbeans complains:

```
Executing: gradle run
Arguments: [-c, /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/hello_client/settings.gradle]

:run
Cannot execute run because the property "mainClass" is not defined or empty.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.17 secs
```

What's the correct way to set the main class for the Netbeans plugin?

Comment: `if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = 'net.bounceme.mordor.Main'
}` seems to fix Netbeans, but doesn't work for me from the CLI.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/35061812/262852

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `build.gradle` file, you can apply `application` plugin first,

```
apply plugin: 'application'
```

And then specify the main class to be run:

```
mainClassName = 'net.bounceme.mordor.Main'
```

I don't really know the Netbeans specific stuff here but `application` plugin will provide the `run` task with necessary configuration to run from command line and hopefully from Netbeans too.

Refer this section in Gralde user guide: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

Comment: yes, I tried that, not sure why, but that plugin caused a gradle build problem.

Comment: I just tried that and it works on the project that you mentioned. run `gradle run` from command line

Comment: I'll play with it.  It seemed to bring up a tangential problem, so I asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890436/cannot-add-gradle-application-plugin before your response.  LOL.  I can delete that question, maybe too much.

Comment: heh, never did a pull request before, so just copied/pasted your solution.  thanks, though :)  **and Netbeans now runs the Java SE from the IDE, which is an added bonus**, however, I'm not quite sure that this the "official" and correct way to use the plugin.  Works for now.

Comment: If you want to specify custom application arguments you can add "cmd-line-args=my custom args" to Properties - Custom variables like it was dscribed here: https://github.com/kelemen/netbeans-gradle-project/wiki/Custom-variables-(properties)